# Basic calculator written in C only adds

Tags: c, calculator

I tried to make a basic calculator but whenever I make my inputs it adds rather than listening to my operator input.

I know that my if and if else statements aren't working but I don't really understand why. When I compile there are no errors and every other way that I've tried has resulted in many errors.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
double num1;
double num2;
double x;
double operator;

printf("First number:\n");
scanf("%lf\n", &num1);

printf("Second number:\n");
scanf("%lf\n", &num2);

printf("Select operator:\n Division\n Multiplication\n Subtraction\n Addition\n");
scanf("%lf\n", &operator);

if (operator == '/' ) {
    x=num1/num2;
}
else if (operator == '*') {
    x=num1*num2;
}
else if (operator == '-') {
    x=num1 - num2;
}
else {
    x=num1 + num2;
}

printf("Result: %lf\n", x);

return 0;
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: "adds rather than listening to my operator input." and "statements aren't working" --> post the exact input used and output seen.  This helps to provide an  answer to your particular case.

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%lf\n", &operator);`   This is trying to read a `double`, but the 'operator' is a single character.  Suggest:  `scanf( " %c\n", &operator );`  and declare the variable `operator` as a `char`, not a `double`

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I'd avoid calling your variable 'operator' (it's a keyword in C++). 
This is your variable:

```cpp
double operator;
```

And here you read it as a double precision floating point number:

```cpp
scanf("%lf\n", &operator);
```

And now you hope to treat it as a char:

```cpp
if(operator == '-')
```

To fix this, change the type of operator to char:

```cpp
char operator;
```

and read it as a char:

```cpp
scanf("%c\n", &operator);
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe it was that simple. One more question, does the == only compare chars? or is the ' ' designating a char?

Comment: Change that to `scanf(" %c", &operator)`

Comment: @GradyWhite `==` can be used to compare any type. The quotes make a `char` constant, and you should compare that with another `char`.

Comment: There's no particular reason to avoid using `operator` as an identifier unless there's a realistic prospect that your code will be compiled as C++. This program, if written in *idiomatic* C++, would be very different.

Comment: The trailing `"\n"` in all `scanf()` should be removed, else `scanf()` blocks until next non-white-space input.

Answer (score 0):

the posted code always results in addition because none of the comparisons ( '/', '-', '*' ) will ever compare equal to a `double`